Standard way of dealing with token auth in boost.beast?
I want to implement token authentification on top of client written in boost.beast. I thing this is not an easy thing: one should carefully look for token expiration(for example, reauthing on auth failure will stop the flow of requests, which could be unacceptable in highly loaded systems. Reauth in advance can be more acceptable), refresh tokens, and other things I can't think of now.
So is there some kind of library to not make mistakes in that? Or maybe some kind of tutorial/guide?

The standard way "in beast" is the same as in any other HTTP library: you implement it (optionally with a library). Boost doesn't offer this, at the moment.
